# MongoDB design model for category and subcategory

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, data-modeling

Hi guys Im having a problem with MongoDB, I do not know how to design DB to support categories & subcategories...

So Im trying to create a Quiz app, with 2 models:

**Question model**

- I will contain question

**Category model**

- It contains category in which question will be

This is what Im trying to accomplish, I want to build Quiz app, the Quiz app will have 3 main categories: A category, B category and C category ...

> Note: I will not have more than 20 subcategories per category

And each of the categories will have their own SubCategories like this: 'A category' will contains Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Test5... same for 'B category' it will contain Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4....

> Note: I will not have more than 3 main categories

And each of this Test1, Test2 subcategories will contain a list of questions

So I based my model like this:

**Category model:**

```
export const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  parent: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category"
  },
  name: { type:String, required:true },
  slug: String,
});
```

**Question Model:**

```
export const QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  question: { type:String, required:true },
  options: [String],
  answers: Array,
  category: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category"
  }
});
```

With one additional catch, is that I would like a Question to be a part of different SubCategories, like it can be a part of 
 *A category > Test 1, B category > Test 2, A category > Test 3,* so I can reuse it between different sub categories

My question is: Is this right way to design database ? Or is there some other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the reference that the *Category* and a *Test* together forms a `tests` collection, and the second collection is the `questions`. There are two models I can think of, and the choice is based upon your query and application needs.

**Model 1:**

```
tests:
    id: "A-Test1"
    category: "A",
    test: "Test1",
    name / description: "...",
    questions: [ "q1", "q2", "q15", "q16", "q25", ... ]

questions:
   id: "q1",
   details: { question: "...", options: [...], answer: [...] }
```

You want to find all questions for category "A" and "Test2":

- Query on tests collection and get the questions.
- Get question details from the questions collection; this would be a
  "join" query, using the aggregation stage `$lookup`.

You want to know if a question belongs to what categories/tests:

- Query the tests collection's questions array.
- Lookup the questions collection for more details about the question.

**Model 2:**

```
tests:
    id: "A-Test1"
    category: "A",
    test: "Test1",
    name / description: "..."

questions:
   id: "q1",
   details: { question: "...", options: [...], answer: [...] },
   tests: [ "A-Test1", "A-Test5", "C-Test2", ... ]
```

You want to find all questions for "A" and "Test2":

- Query the questions collection, on the tests array.
- Lookup the tests collection for more details about the test.

You want to know a question belongs to what categories/tests:

- Query the questions collection, on the tests array.
- Lookup the tests collection for more details about each test.

Comment: Thank you so much, for your answer :)